# Can Quorum Nodes be accessed via https?

Tags: web3js, quorum

I  have a Dapp which has SSL certificate. I am unable to access Quorum Nodes via https and http as the Dapp is https.

Can anyone please suggest me a method to solve this issue.

(Node access via web3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTPS connections are not supported by GoQuorum at the moment.

You should be able to achieve the same using SSL termination or similar. Take a look at the following doc to see how this is done with nginx: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/terminating-ssl-http/

Answer (score 0):

This might not be a good answer, but this question did pique my curiosity as I do have a fair amount of experience with SSL pinning and essentially bypassing it or figuring out what needs to be passed in headers and how tokens are handled (yes I'm very opportunistic) to look at apps (mainly I make automations). I've done this for years, even when you have SSL pinning and behavioural checks(like checking for rooted phone etc)- I'm good at getting around it.

This all said I'm new as hell to writing smart contracts. I literally just looked up Quorum (looks like its JPMorgan private blockchain based on a soft fork of ethereum) because I had no idea what that was. So my advice is going to be somewhat general.

I'm assuming this is something along the lines of an x509 certificate for authentication right? It might be worthwhile to try renewing the certificate and private key(things can be that simple, but yet frustrating).

I think nodes that are configured to use TLS for transport would not be able to  communicate with nodes that use unencrypted transport connection. When you have security features enabled, you have to use TLS to ensure that communication is encrypted. So I'm guessing you would need to reassess all your nodes/clusters. Restart everything. Also monitoring  - if its there(I am assuming it is) I think you'll need a different .pem file for that.. and frankly it should be possible to configure whatever http traffic to go through https.

I'm not sure if this is wholly feasible with Dapps, but turning on a packet sniffer for debugging might be helpful. Burp suite, mitm, even postman etc etc. There are even ones available for your phone (I personally really like HTTPCatcher for my iphone). Unfortunately if you have an android you will need to root the device in order to place self signed cert on root to sniff https traffic.

Again very interesting question, I'm just not fully grounded with dapps yet so these are mainly my musings.